# Find string inside an array of string. (C code)

Tags: c

I have got this template.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 10
int findTarget(char *target, char nameptr[SIZE][80], int size);
int main()
{
    char nameptr[SIZE][80];
    char t[40];
    int i, result, size;

    printf("Enter no. of names: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    printf("Enter %d names: ", size);
    for (i = 0; i<size; i++)
        scanf("%s", nameptr[i]);
    printf("Enter target name: ");
    scanf("\n");
    gets(t);
    result = findTarget(t, nameptr, size);
    printf("findTarget(): %d\n", result);
    return 0;
}
int findTarget(char *target, char nameptr[SIZE][80], int size)
{
    /* write your code here */
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (nameptr[i] == *target)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

And the code under /* write your code here */ is my code.
The code doesn't work. I think something is wrong with (nameptr[i] == *target).

Examples of output:

```
Enter no. of names: 4
Enter 4 names: Peter Paul John Mary
Enter target name: John
findTarget(): 2

Enter no. of names: 4
Enter 4 names: peter mary john steve
Enter target name: may
findTarget(): -1
```

I think the template is correct cos its provided by school.

Thank you for helps.

Comment: "I think something is wrong with (nameptr[i] == *target)". Yes, you are right. Strings in C cannot be compared using `==`. Use [`strcmp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp). Also, tell your teachers that they should never be using `gets` which is inherently unsafe as it does no bounds checks.

Comment: I replaced  (nameptr[i] == *target) with (strcmp(nameptr[i], *target)) and the program clashed. :(

Comment: `*target` needs to be `target`. Your compiler should have given you warnings. Never ignore them. And read the man page thoroughly. You are not using the strcmp return value correctly.

Comment: Oh ok  think I know. It should be (!strcmp(nameptr[i], target))

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
if (nameptr[i] == *target)
```

is wrong because you are comparing a pointer with an integer and that makes no sense. Also, in order to compare two strings, use [`strcmp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp). Using `==` will compare the pointers and not the content of them.

Fix:

```
if (strcmp(nameptr[i], target) == 0)
```